# std::move with && (rvalue reference) as a member function return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I just want to initialize a member data `oneObj` of `class Two` as below which compiles fine. I would like to know whether it is advisable to use `std::move` and `&&` together to initialize an object or just pass the `oneObj` as a reference to `InitObjOne` as follows `InitObjOne(One & obj)` and initialize it. is there any advantage over another. Please clarify.

**Note:** The `InitObjOne` need to perform few actions for creating an object of `One`, I've just given a skeleton of the functionalities here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class One
{
    public:
    int x;
};

class Two
{
   public:
   Two();

   private:
   One oneObj;
   One && InitObjOne();
};

Two::Two() : oneObj(InitObjOne())
{

}

One && Two::InitObjOne()
{
    One aObjOne;
    return std::move(aObjOne);
}

int main() 
{
    Two two;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Two::InitObjOne` returns a reference to a local variable. You should probably [find a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn references properly.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but always prefer making initialization in constructor rather than some tricky, easily forgettable to call functions. If there is a risk that you forget to call it, you will forget to call it one day or another.